# Blocked IP on CloudFlare keeps connecting and attacking server

Tags: domain-name-system, cloudflare

I have a NodeJS server with HTTPS and certificates. The DNS is on CloudFlare.

The host receives a connection every day at 3:32am from `3.8.236.120`, an AWS host in the UK. The crawler launches requests to the same 4 pages repeatedly around that time, 26 requests in 5 minutes. Although the number seems manageable, this is the most likely culprit, and the only activity the web server shows at that time every day.

I blocked the IP in the CloudFlare Web Application Firewall, along with others that have attacked in the past:

```
(ip.src in {194.48.199.78 5.43.32.229 92.220.10.100 107.172.137.111 193.169.254.179 149.3.170.66 47.243.233.244 3.8.236.120}) or (ip.geoip.country in {"IN" "ID"})
```

I checked that the rule is enabled. And yet, this IP address is still connecting to the server via DNS. Here is the server log for one connection:

```
GET /pt/sumario 200 143.483 ms - 13972
[2024-02-16T03:31:18.155Z] /pt/amostras  ::  ::ffff:3.8.236.120  ::  Python-urllib/3.11
[2024-02-16T03:31:18.156Z] Host =  ginja.org
```

I suspect there is some setting on CloudFlare that conflicts with this rule. How can I block all requests from this IP address?

### Update

To answer the comments:

- I blocked the IPv6 address on CloudFlare and still get traffic from it.
- I don't know if the crawler accessed `robots.txt` because it was in the public directory and I didn't track its visits. I am tracking them now.
- One request every 12 seconds seems light indeed. But I get traffic from this crawler every day at the same time, and some days my server is down at that time, so I want to rule out this bot first. Also, I have another server checking every minute whether this one is up and running, and on the days I consider under attack, the server doesn't log any activity from the health checker, so it's possible that the crawler floods my server with so many requests at the same time that they don't get logged.

Comment: Does the crawler access `/robots.txt`?

Comment: Also, the logged IP is `::ffff:3.8.236.120` which is an IPv4-mapped IPv6 address and not the same as the IPv4 address `3.8.236.120`.

Comment: `26 requests in 5 minutes. Although the number seems manageable` one request every 12 seconds? What is your threshold for "denial of service"?

Comment: It looks like it is coming in as IPv6 address. Please block it in the CloudFlare as well and see.

Comment: @AlexD I don't know if the crawler checked `robots.txt`, but I started logging that. I blocked the IPv6 address on CloudFlare but I still get traffic on the server from it. I updated the question.

Comment: @MichaelC I blocked the IPv6 address on CloudFlare but I still get traffic on the server from it. I updated the question.

Comment: @GregAskew Indeed, it seems light, but it's the most likely culprit for now and I want to rule that out first. I updated the question.

Comment: What is being denied?

Comment: @GregAskew I have another virtual machine checking the health of this service every minute. and every other day at 3.32 am, this server doesn't respond to the health check.

Comment: Five unauthenticated requests isn't what most would consider a denial of service.

Comment: @GregAskew Fair point. Shall I edit the question and title to focus on blocking an IPv4 or IPv6 address on CloudFlare?

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I found the culprit and added an answer. I should probably change the question to fit the answer and not mention DoS, but then most of these comments won't make sense. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that my DNS on CloudFlare was not proxied. It was "DNS only". And so the rules on the Web Application Firewall did not apply.

When I changed the DNS on `root` and `www` to be proxied through CloudFlare, then the rules started working.

And it turned out to not be a DoS attack after all, as the comments suggested, because one request every 12 seconds is quite light. But, after ruling out this cause, I found the real culprit.

Today I learned that CloudFlare traffic has to be proxied to be protected.

Comment: yup you have to proxy it else as it will shown in the dashboard your server can be directly reached.